# Homebridge custom accessories creation

Tags: node.js

Is it possible to create a customer Apple HomeKit accessory ? I want to create a textbox which I can display custom text or values.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can create a plugin and that plugin will read from a listener (a door that opens or a thermometer) and after that it can write the value using HTTP post in a web server that has a website with that value. Just an idea.